# JQuery function inside another function is executed first

Tags: jquery

I have this two function

```js
var hapusKelas = function(namaelement, namaclass) {
  $(namaelement).removeClass(namaclass);
}

var populateData = function(link, namamd) {
  $.get(link, function(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    var isitable = '';
    $('#isihadiahmd').empty();
    $.each(data, function(i, toko) {
      var count = 0;
      var jmlitem = Object.keys(toko.data).length;
      $.each(toko.data, function(j, barang) {
        setTimeout(function() {

          count += 1;
          if (count == 1) {
            isitable = '';
            isitable = '<tr><td rowspan="' + jmlitem + '">' + namamd + '</td><td rowspan="' + jmlitem + '">' + toko.nama_toko + '</td><td>' + barang.nama + '</td><td>' + barang.qty + '</td></tr>';

          } else {
            isitable = '';
            isitable = '<tr><td>' + barang.nama + '</td><td>' + barang.qty + '</td></tr>';
          }
          $('#isihadiahmd').append(isitable);
        }, 2000);
      })

    })

  })
  hapusKelas('.dimmer.md', 'active');
}
```

Every tutorial said that if I want to run hapusKelas function, I have to call the function inside populateData function. I have done that but everytime I call populateData, hapusKelas executed on the beginning of populateData.

First thing I want to achieve is call `hapusKelas` function after `populateData` is finish appending table on a page. Please,, give me someway to solve this.

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous function, move `hapusKelas('.dimmer.md', 'active');` inside the success callback

Comment: What is the purpose of the timeout? Note that it writes all the table at one instance. Maybe you wanted a 2 sec delay between the display of each row? And: it will not output the first row of the data.

Comment: @trincot yeah I want to delay between the display of each row, what is the best way to do that??

Comment: you can also try $.ajaxSetup({async: false}); before $.get

Comment: `async: false` is not a recommended solution: it will block user-interaction.

Comment: @imilah, I posted an answer that also deals with the delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an asynchronous callback, and even in that callback you have a time out. If you want to only run your final function after the rows have been displayed you need to call it inside that time-out callback.

Your purpose seems to display the rows one by one, but the time-outs you currently have will all fire at the same time. You could solve this by putting those time-outs in an asynchronous loop construct.

I would also first collect all the HTML you want to generate inside an array, with one piece per row, and then do the asynchronous loop on that array.

You can do this as follows:

```
var populateData = function(link, namamd) {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var isitable = []; // make it an array
        // Collect html in this array:
        $.each(data, function(i, toko) {
            var jmlitem = Object.keys(toko.data).length;
            var count = 0;
            $.each(toko.data, function(j, barang) {
                // Use jQuery methods for creating your content
                var cells = [$('<td>').text(barang.nama), $('<td>').text(barang.qty)];
                if (count == 0) { // Prefix the two columns
                    cells = [$('<td>').attr('rowspan', jmlitem).text(namamd),
                             $('<td>').attr('rowspan', jmlitem).text(toko.nama_toko)]
                            .concat(cells);
                }
                isitable.push($('<tr>').append(cells));
                count++;
            });
        });
        // Display the result in steps:
        $('#isihadiahmd').empty();
        (function loop(i) {
            if (i >= isitable.length) {
                hapusKelas('.dimmer.md', 'active');
                return; // all done
            }
            $('#isihadiahmd').append(isitable[i]);
            setTimeout(loop.bind(null, i+1), 500); // delay before displaying next row
        }(0)); // start loop at index 0
    });
};
```

Comment: waaaaaa thank a lot @trincot... I never think about colecting all the HTML first.

Answer (score 1):

Call hapusKelas function once your service call returns success call back...check where i called that function (before settimeout ends)

```
                var hapusKelas = function(namaelement, namaclass) {
              $(namaelement).removeClass(namaclass);
            }

            var populateData = function(link, namamd) {
              $.get(link, function(data) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                var isitable = '';
                $('#isihadiahmd').empty();
                $.each(data, function(i, toko) {
                  var count = 0;
                  var jmlitem = Object.keys(toko.data).length;
                  $.each(toko.data, function(j, barang) {
                    setTimeout(function() {

                      count += 1;
                      if (count == 1) {
                        isitable = '';
                        isitable = '<tr><td rowspan="' + jmlitem + '">' + namamd + '</td><td rowspan="' + jmlitem + '">' + toko.nama_toko + '</td><td>' + barang.nama + '</td><td>' + barang.qty + '</td></tr>';

                      } else {
                        isitable = '';
                        isitable = '<tr><td>' + barang.nama + '</td><td>' + barang.qty + '</td></tr>';
                      }
                      $('#isihadiahmd').append(isitable);
                       hapusKelas('.dimmer.md', 'active'); ///**called here**
                    }, 2000);
                  })

                })

              })

            }
```

Comment: Perhaps explain for the OP what you changed and why so they understand where they went wrong.

Comment: i agree @brad.. Call hapusKelas function once your service call returns success call back.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was due to the $.get() is **asynchronous**,the next line of code will execute before completing the ajax request.

I can suggest two method to resolve this.

1) Call `hapusKelas('.dimmer.md', 'active');` inside the success calback functions last line.

2) use $.ajax() instead of using $.get() with `async:false` option